# What are the applications of classical logic?

Tags: logic

Can someone tell me some applications, direct or indirect of classical logics to solve real life problems? Outside of universities where it is used and for what?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the fact that it is the essential underpinning of all of probability theory (which itself is used to solve a dozen of real life problems) count?

Comment: Yes count. It is a indirect aplication.

Comment: Do computers count?

Comment: What do you mean by "direct or indirect"? And why are you asking this question? Non-classical logical has some niche applications. Classical logic pervades everyday life.

Comment: I want know if worth to study methods to optimize logical deductions in computers, I want know if are useful such methods. Direct is when logic is used in something, indirect is when logic is used in something which is used in some another thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most "classic" example of applications of classic (propositional) logic is computer design.

See [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra), [Logic gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate) and [Digital circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_electronics).